# Pass a function to PoolThread

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection

I've some classes that generate lot of threads and the application is really slowly and takes a lot of memory. We have decided to use a Poolthread to decrease the threads overhead. The `PoolThread` is managed in a class and I have a question: how can I pass a generic function as parameter and execute once is in the PoolThread?
E.g.

```
public void executeFunction( myFunction) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void Run() {
            run the function that I've passed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Have you looked at `ExecutorService`?

Comment: *"I have a question: it's possible pass a generic function as parameter and execute once is in the PoolThread?"* - Answer: yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As functions have no proper existence in java, you would better give the executorService the Runnable (or even better the Callable) object containing the code to execute, with the method returning you the corresponding Future.

In fact, believe it or not, this very method exists in ExecutorService : [`<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29)

The [`Future#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) method will allow you to wait until the result is obtained.